Problems with G and control
the original is G, moving items. However, it now moving like with G and control, block by block, and i have to click G and control to the original effect. what should i do to fix it?

You haven't got Snapping turned on (horseshoe icon hilighted in white/blue on the top toolbar) have you?

Horseshoe? I think you hurt all magnets' feelings ‎

It didn't complain the last time I called it that, but 'magnet' it will be in future! :^)

are you sure you don't have the snap grid on ?
